# Finding a system path in flask from a Pythonanywhere server

Tags: python, file, flask, server, pythonanywhere

I have created an input file box in the front end, such that the user can be able to upload a file from his/her own system and the flask has to read the file. But it works on the local host but was not working after hosting it on pythonanywhere.

```
enter code here`    from apps import app
                    from flask import  jsonify,render_template, request,json
                    @app.route('/fileData',methods=['GET','POST'])
                    def fileData()
                              if request.method=='POST':
                                         address=request.form['address']
                                         file_location =address

                                      workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
                                         sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Here the address is the address of the file which is the user's file and the code has to read that file.

Comment: Do you want to open a file that is uploaded by the user or the file that is already on the machine you run flask on? In your question, you are referring to both situations and it's not clear.

Comment: Actually, I want to read a file which is uploaded by the user! Sorry I have put the question in a way more confusing.

Comment: Your code as its written does not allow the user to upload a file.  Instead, they upload the path to a file, and then the file is read from the filesystem of the computer that is running the server.